# 2 dimensional matrix in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the following array:

```
var list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
```

and these for loops:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
       document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML = 
    }
}
```

how can i print them in a 'textarea' having the following format:

1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9

Comment: Does it have to be `for` loops?

Comment: You should probably be using e.g. `lists.length` and list[i].length` instead of hard-coding the sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so maybe something like...

```js
var list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

var html = '';
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      html += list[i][j] + " ";               
    }
    html += '<br />';
} 
  
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="content">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of checking inside the inner loop when to add the`<br/>`, just do it unconditionally in the outer loop after the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be for loops, you can also use `map`:

```js
var list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
    someId = document.getElementById( 'someID' );

someId.innerHTML = '<pre>' + list.map(function (row) {
    return row.join(' '); 
}).join('<br>') + '</pre>';
```

```html
<div id="someID"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct the string to output in the inner loops, and after the outer loop you make your element to show that string.

Comment: Belive me, I have tried such solutions, but didn`t manage to pull this off... can you give me an example maybe? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this iterating through each idea:

add `<div id="someID"></div>`

Then instead of hard coding 3 use list.length and list[i].length then do:

```
var list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

var temp = "";
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < list[i].length; j++) {
       temp+=list[i][j] + " ";
    }
    temp+="<br>";
} 
document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML = temp;
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0k1tf5wh/

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

To display it in a div, you'll need to wrap each row in a div, because of how HTML handles whitespace:

See: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ox33t7gk/)

```
var list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
var html = '';
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    html += list[i].join(' ');
}
document.getElementById('someID').innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that.

`console.log` will print one line per call on most browsers.

You can use line breaking characters (`'\n'`) to print to a file, if you are working on an environment where you have access to IO (i.e.: NodeJS).

In HTML you can use the `<br>` tag, paragraphs (`<p>`), or you can place each line in a `div`. For example, with `<br>` you could do it like this:

```
var list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML += list[i].join(" ") + "<br>";
}
```

Remember that each element of the outer array is an array itself, so you can print them as one element each with the `join` method from the `Array` type.